"strong" conditional independence
In classification problems, a special kind of statistical independence is often encountered.
Let say I've got samples whose classes/labels are $y_i$. I'm trying to classify them from observables/measures $x_i$.
A common independence properties that can be encountered is: $p\left(x_1,...,x_N|y_1,...,y_N\right)=\prod_{i}p\left(x_i|y_i\right)$, which is stronger than conditional independence: $p\left(x_1,...,x_N|y_1,...,y_N\right)=\prod_{i}p\left(x_i|y\right)$
Does this strong conditional independence has a name?
